# How to store forest plot in an object to be recalled in R?

Tags: r, graph, r-forestplot

Just a little question on how to store and recall forest plot in R. I am creating forest plot using the meta function in R. I may have the need to store the graph and recall in the viewer at a later time. I've tried with this expression:

```
forest.meta <- forest(meta,  [...])
```

where [...] are the options, but when I type "forest.meta", I get a "null" error rather than the graph again in the viewer.

Where I am wrong?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get `NULL` because that's what the function returns, much as base R's `plot` does. It's not like `ggplot` where an actual plot object is returned for you to manipulate.

However, all is not lost. Since `forest` plots using grid graphics, we can grab the contents of the plotting window, store them as a collection of graphical objects, and plot them again later:

```r
library(meta)

data(Olkin1995)

m1 <- metabin(ev.exp, n.exp, ev.cont, n.cont,
              data = Olkin1995, subset = c(41, 47, 51, 59),
              sm = "RR", method = "I",
              studlab = paste(author, year))

forest(m1)
```

[image]

```r
# Now grab the plot
my_plot <- grid::grid.grab()
```

The plot is now stored as `my_plot`, so suppose we want to use the plotting window for something else meantime

```r
plot(1:10)
```

[image]

When we're done, we can recall the exact same plot by doing:

```r
grid::grid.newpage()
grid::grid.draw(my_plot)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.